# Backported StreamSupport on Java 7/Android

Tags: android, java-7

I mean this library: http://sourceforge.net/projects/streamsupport/

It meant to be compatible with Java8 Streams, so I tried to run some examples from Java8 docs, like this:

```
IntStream.range(1, 4).forEach(System.out::println);
```

But .range is not defined anywhere. From that library documentation:

> streamsupport is a backport of the Java 8 java.util.function (functional interfaces) and java.util.stream (streams) API for users of Java 6 or 7 supplemented with selected additions from java.util.concurrent which didn't exist back in Java 6.

But:
- I can't find any single example how to use that backported library
- As you can see, I also can't use even simplest scenario from Java8.

Can anybody give me some example how to use backported StreamSupport, or some link to documentation?

[edit]

```
import java8.util.function.Consumer;

IntStreams.range(1, 4).forEach(new Consumer<Integer>(){
         public void accept(Integer next){
                 System.out.println(next);
         }
});
```

Error message:

> Error:(126, 35) error: method forEach in interface IntStream cannot be
>   applied to given types; required: IntConsumer found: > reason: actual argument > cannot be converted to IntConsumer by method
>   invocation conversion

If I change Consumer to IntConsumer:

> Error:(127, 59) error: type IntConsumer does not take parameters

Comment: note it's IntStreams not IntStream.

Comment: java8 doc says IntStream, LongStream etc

Comment: Yep - it's a change from the orignal - Java 7 doesn't support static methods on Interfaces - I don't think anyone has backported that yet.

Comment: This library appears to be licensed as GPL 2.0.  I am not an IP lawyer, but my understanding is that by using this library, you would need to license the "derived work" (i.e. your own app) under the same license.  And that you will need to publicly publish the source of our app for others to use.

Comment: @vonWippersnap No, the [streamsupport license](https://sourceforge.net/projects/streamsupport/files/1.5.5-stable/LICENSE) is GPL2, CE (GNU General Public License, version 2, `with the Classpath Exception`), i.e. the same as the `OpenJDK` license. No need to worry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't used this library, but, looking at the code (http://sourceforge.net/p/streamsupport/code/ci/default/tree/src/main/java/java8/util/stream/IntStreams.java) I think this should work

```
import java8.util.stream.IntStreams;
IntStreams.range(1, 4).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Java 7 Style

```
import java8.util.stream.IntStreams;     
import java8.util.function.IntConsumer;

IntStreams.range(1, 4).forEach(new IntConsumer(){
        public void accept(int next){
                System.out.println(next);
        }
});
```

**Updated** switched to IntConsumer. Using a plain Consumer below

```
import java8.util.stream.IntStreams;     
import java8.util.function.Consumer;

IntStreams.range(1, 4)
        .boxed()
        .forEach(new Consumer<Integer>(){
                public void accept(Integer next){
                        System.out.println(next);
                }
});
```

Comment: Now I'm getting error: "Method references are not supported at this language level"

Comment: Have you set up Retro Lambda also? https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda They recommend in your IDE to set the Java version to 8 (but don't use the Java 8 APIs directly). Then in your build use Java 7 w/ RetroLambda.

Comment: No, I haven't but I don't need lambdas actually, stream will be enough. I can't set java version to 8 in my Android Studio

Comment: Ok - will update the code example to a Java 7 way of writing it.

Comment: Are there any docs describing in details differences between that backported lib and native java8 streams? I mean api descripion and code examples, not only basic description without any explanation

Comment: Not that I can see. It's a pity it's on sourceforge rather than github too.

Comment: Updated with IntStream and standard Object Stream versions.